# R cut, exclude infinite

Tags: r, nan

I'm trying to create categories for a ratio with cut function. I need to create a different category for the values that were infinite or NaN.

Example table:

```
set.seed(1)
tbl_a<-data.frame(a=round(runif(200, -1,1)*10,0)/10, b=rep(seq(0,9), 10))
tbl_a$ratio=tbl_a$a/tbl_a$b
```

My try was:

```
tbl_a$ratio_G<-ifelse(tbl_a$ratio %in% c(Inf, -Inf,NaN), 'xx',
          cut(tbl_a$ratio, breaks=c(0,0.1,0.2,0.27,0.35,0.54,0.90,0.99,Inf), right=FALSE))
```

**But instead of the breacks I get level values.**

How can I get the original breaks and also the 'xx' for the NaN or Infinite? Thanks.

**EDITION: I found another issue when I group the results, after applying akrun's suggestion.** So I changed the breaks to show the case:

```
tbl_a$ratio_G<-ifelse(tbl_a$ratio %in% c(Inf, -Inf,NaN), 'xx',
          as.character(cut(tbl_a$ratio, breaks=c(-Inf,-1,-0.1,0.1,0.2,0.5,0.99,Inf), right=FALSE)))


library (dplyr)
tbl_a%>%group_by(ratio_G)%>%summarise(cant=n())
```

So, I get:

```
    ratio_G  cant
       (chr) (int)
  [-0.1,0.1)   98
  [-1,-0.1)    40
  [0.1,0.2)    22
  [0.2,0.5)    15
 [0.5,0.99)     5
         xx    20
```

But this is not ordered. I should get:

```
ratio_G cant
(chr)   (int)
[-1,-0.1)   40
[-0.1,0.1)  98
[0.1,0.2)   22
[0.2,0.5)   15
[0.5,0.99)  5
xx  20
```

I think this happens because the labels are characters. This is a problem created by the solution of the main issue, so I guess it is still the same question.

Comment: Inside the `ifelse`, the `factor` (from `cut` converts to `integer`).  you can wrap it with `as.character` i.e. `as.character(cut(tbl_a..`

Comment: @akrun, the problem is that doing this, it cannot order them. Do you know how to avoid this issue?

Comment: Just saw your new edits. Since you do want the default labels that come from `cut`, I'm deleting my answer as it really does not contribute much beyond @akrun's original comment. As for ordering the result, I don't have much there other than to suggest mutating another column with the integer levels from `cut` and then `arrange` by those.